# Pattern matching generic types… well… generically

Tags: swift, reflection, pattern-matching

I'm trying to use reflection to dynamically read all properties in a class, and then switch upon each property to detect its type. Sadly, I'm not sure how to do this, as the Swift compiler keeps throwing errors.

Here's an example of what I would like to achieve:

```swift
class Property<SpecialKey, Value> where SpecialKey: Codable, Value: Codable { … }

class CustomProperty: Property { … }

switch CustomProperty() {
case is Property: // Requires that I specify the generics, e.g.: Property<String, String>. I just want to match Property<T, U>, where T: Codable and U: Codable.
  break
default:
  break
}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an internal typealias to Property:

```
class Property<SpecialKey, Value> where SpecialKey: Codable, Value: Codable {
    typealias SpecialKeyTypeAlias = SpecialKey
    typealias ValueTypeAlias = Value
}
```

And then provide the generics like this:

```
switch CustomProperty() {
case is Property<CustomProperty.SpecialKeyTypeAlias, CustomProperty.ValueTypeAlias>:
  break
default:
  break
}
```

However, I didn't understand the premise of your question, because as the yellow error when we write this tells us:

> 'is' test is always true

The concrete types passed to Property are part of the class definition, so they will always be the same. Moreover, even if we didn't provide the generics and just write `case is Property`, that would always be true too, as the class definition inherits from Property.

Comment: The premise was to essentially erase said concrete types, like AnyCollection does for Collection. Anyway, thank you for your answer!

Comment: @JacobCXDev no worries! I do want to just say also that I'm not convinced you need Type Erasure like AnyCollection does from the code you've provided, I may be saying this prematurely as I haven't seen much, but you may be able to make Property a protocol with associatedtypes and then extend that protocol. Type Erasure is really not the most clean (or performant) way of writing generic code. Also I should note the benefit of generic code is that it has no idea what the underlying types are, so I can't think of any reason to pattern match it.

Comment: The code I provided was no more than pseudocode. What I'm actually attempting is to automatically generate database fields for a FluentKit migration, given a FluentKit model (using FluentKit + Vapor). I've been trying to use reflection to switch over each property to detect its type, but I've since found that — to some extent — this functionality already exists undocumented. Now I'm just trying to manipulate the existing API to get A) the keys for each field, and B) the value type for each field.